# Issues running Extreme Reality's Mac Samples

Tags: macos, motion-detection

Trying to get an understanding of the this new Extreme Reality SDK for gesture/skeletal tracking for a project.  They have a SDK for Mac, which includes samples.  Tried running some of the .app files in the bin folder to no avail, keep getting the application can not be opened.  Not sure if the source needs to be loaded into Xcode / Unity and built?  Has anyone gotten these to run?  Extreme Reality's site 'forum' has yet to turn up any answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an employee of Extreme Reality, I'll gladly help you with our SDK.

> Tried running some of the .app files in the bin folder to no avail

I will assume that you have downloaded the latest SDK from our site (latest update was on 31/12/2015), and I assume you got "Can't open application" OSX message.
Sometimes during the installation, the application permissions get wrong.

To fix this issue, please open the "Terminal" applicaiton and enter these commands:

```
sudo chmod 755 /Applications/ExtremeMotionSDK/OSX/Samples/Unity/ProximitySample/bin/ProximitySample.app/Contents/MacOS/ProximitySample
sudo chmod 755 /Applications/ExtremeMotionSDK/OSX/Samples/Unity/UIConceptsSample/bin/UIConceptsSample.app/Contents/MacOS/UIConceptsSample
sudo chmod 755 /Applications/ExtremeMotionSDK/OSX/Samples/Unity/VisualSkeletonSample/bin/VisualSkeletonSample.app/Contents/MacOS/VisualSkeletonSample
```

This will fix the permissions for all 3 pre-compiled samples and you can run them. Of course you will  need a web camera connected to the mac. Also please note, that the trial license is for 30 days.

> Not sure if the source needs to be loaded into Xcode / Unity and built?

To build the sample applicaiton on MacOS, you will need Unity. Right now we have only Unity samples for MacOS, not XCode.

PS. If you have any issues with XTR3D SDK, please don't hesitate to contact us at: support@xtr3d.com